# setting color of drawable in ArrayAdapter effects all items

Tags: android, listview, android-drawable

Setting the color for a drawable changes the color for all items in list.
Setting text inside the textviews works as expected, but the color of the Drawable is overwriting all existing items. (the drawable returned by getDrawable() is a new Instance for each item, checked by debuging).
If i uses different Drawables its also working.

I put some comments inside the code where the problem is.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    public MyAdapter(Activity activity, List<Item> data) {
        super(activity, R.layout.list_item_Item, data);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {
            result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_Item, parent, false);
        } else {
            result = convertView;
        }

        final Item item = getItem(position);

        if (item == null) {
            return result;
        }

        ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.item_name)).setText(item.getTitle());
        ((TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.item_description)).setText(item.getDescription());

        // final modifier is just for testing inside onClickListener also without it is not working
        final ImageView logo = ((ImageView) result.findViewById(R.id.item_icon));
        logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.fancy_icon);
        // logo.getDrawable() is giving a new Instance for each list entry

        // this line overwrites all drawable colors in the complete list
        logo.getDrawable().setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(item.isChecked()?Color.GREEN:Color.GREY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

        result.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // this works as expected, and change only the curent one
                logo.getDrawable().setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to load the drawable again from resources

```
Drawable d = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.item_icon);
d.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN))
logo.setBackground(d);
```

but without any effect.

Can anybody see where my mistake is?

Comment: thanks @0X0nosugar  I didn't find that post. It was the right hint.

Comment: You're welcome :)